# hiding network activity indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [webView loadRequest:request];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad {
   app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

I want to hide the network activity indicator after webpage is loaded. I had written the above code. But the indicator is not hiding after the webpage is fully loaded.

Anyone please help.

Comment: app is of type UIApplication * right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The method should be called `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`. The argument must present.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { 
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

(2) Make sure you set `self` as a delegate of the web view.